# how to create a progress bar in CSS by transition element

Tags: css, progress-bar, css-transitions, loading

Hello How can I create a progress bar in CSS by transition element.

```
.pro {
    height: 2px;
    width: 100vw;
    transition: width 2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `keyframes` for this.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn'), pro = document.querySelector('.pro')

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  pro.classList.remove('progress');
  
  addPro();
  
});

function addPro() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    pro.classList.add('progress');
  }, 200)
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.pro {
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.pro.progress {
  animation: progress 1.75s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  from{
    width: 0;
  }to {
    width: 100vw;
  }   
}
  
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pro progress"></div>
</div>

<div class="btn">show animation again</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not a progress bar but kind of progress bar .
It will extend to `90vw` when hovered on red pill

```css
.pro {
  height: 20px;
  width: 10vw;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: width 2s linear;
  background-color: red;
}

.pro:hover {
  width: 90vw
}
```

```html
<div class="pro"></div>
```

Comment: I know how to do this with animations but want to know how can I do it with transition.

Comment: This is with transition only , what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry actually my comment was for first Ans. But also in your answer It will only work if I will hover. Can it happen without hovering on progress bar.     Actually I am following lectures of "Code with Harry". He sad it in his video to do this by animations and transitions separately. I know how to do this with animation but not with transition property to do without "hovering".       I am a begineer actually.

Comment: You can use JavaScript along with transition because transition need a trigger (hover, click.....) but with `setinterval` it will run automatic after certain time while animations don't need trigger but we can use one if want. If you are open to that than can show that also